# find matching 'begin' - 'end' and highlight them

Tags: eclipse-rcp, xtext

I am a newbie in developing a DSL in Xtext. I would like to add a feature of highlighting the matching start and end of a code block. In my language every function must start with 'begin' and end with 'end' and same with if conditions and loops. I need to highlight the matching/corresponding 'end' when the cursor is on the 'begin'. for example below, I need to highlight the corresponding first 'end' when the cursor is on the second 'begin':

```
function X 
  begin
     if a>b
       begin
         a=b;
       end
   end
```

Any help with that please?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i dont think the support for that is very good. if you can live with a minor solution you could try the following

The Grammar

```
Model:
    greetings+=Greeting*;

Greeting:
    'if' name=ID 'endif';
```

In the UiModule

```
@Override
public ICharacterPairMatcher bindICharacterPairMatcher() {
    return new MyDslCharacterPairMatcher(new char[] { '(', ')', '{', '}', '[', ']' });
}
```

with

```
public class MyDslCharacterPairMatcher extends DefaultCharacterPairMatcher {

    public MyDslCharacterPairMatcher(char[] chars) {
        super(chars);
    }


    @Override
    public IRegion match(IDocument document, int offset, int length) {
        if (document instanceof IXtextDocument) {
            IXtextDocument xtextDocument = (IXtextDocument)document;

            IRegion result = xtextDocument.readOnly(new IUnitOfWork<IRegion, XtextResource>() {

                @Override
                public IRegion exec(XtextResource state) throws Exception {
                    MyDslGrammarAccess ga = state.getResourceServiceProvider().get(MyDslGrammarAccess.class);

                    ICompositeNode root = state.getParseResult().getRootNode();
                    ILeafNode matchNode = NodeModelUtils.findLeafNodeAtOffset(root, offset);
                    EObject object = NodeModelUtils.findActualSemanticObjectFor(matchNode);
                    if (object instanceof Greeting) {
                        Greeting g = (Greeting)object;
                        if (matchNode.getGrammarElement() == ga.getGreetingAccess().getIfKeyword_0()) {
                            ICompositeNode objectNode = NodeModelUtils.findActualNodeFor(object);
                            for (INode n : objectNode.getAsTreeIterable()) {
                                if (n.getGrammarElement() != null && n.getGrammarElement() == ga.getGreetingAccess().getEndifKeyword_2()) {
                                    return new Region(n.getOffset(), n.getLength());
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        if (matchNode.getGrammarElement() == ga.getGreetingAccess().getEndifKeyword_2()) {
                            ICompositeNode objectNode = NodeModelUtils.findActualNodeFor(object);
                            for (INode n : objectNode.getAsTreeIterable()) {
                                if (n.getGrammarElement() != null && n.getGrammarElement() == ga.getGreetingAccess().getIfKeyword_0()) {
                                    return new Region(n.getOffset(), n.getLength());
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    return null;
                }

            });
            if (result != null) {
                return result;
            }
        }
        return super.match(document, offset, length);
    }

}
```

Unfortunately JFace only Highlight a single Character.
if you want more i think you have to hook into IOccurrenceComputer
(you have to have mark occurences on then)

```
package org.xtext.example.mydsl1.ui;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.eclipse.core.runtime.SubMonitor;
import org.eclipse.emf.ecore.EObject;
import org.eclipse.jface.text.ITextSelection;
import org.eclipse.jface.text.Position;
import org.eclipse.jface.text.source.Annotation;
import org.eclipse.xtext.nodemodel.ICompositeNode;
import org.eclipse.xtext.nodemodel.ILeafNode;
import org.eclipse.xtext.nodemodel.INode;
import org.eclipse.xtext.nodemodel.util.NodeModelUtils;
import org.eclipse.xtext.resource.XtextResource;
import org.eclipse.xtext.ui.editor.XtextEditor;
import org.eclipse.xtext.ui.editor.model.IXtextDocument;
import org.eclipse.xtext.ui.editor.occurrences.DefaultOccurrenceComputer;
import org.eclipse.xtext.util.CancelIndicator;
import org.eclipse.xtext.util.TextRegion;
import org.eclipse.xtext.util.concurrent.CancelableUnitOfWork;
import org.xtext.example.mydsl1.myDsl.Greeting;
import org.xtext.example.mydsl1.services.MyDslGrammarAccess;

public class MyDslOccurrenceComputer extends DefaultOccurrenceComputer {

    @Override
    public Map<Annotation, Position> createAnnotationMap(XtextEditor editor,
            ITextSelection selection, SubMonitor monitor) {

        final IXtextDocument document = editor.getDocument();

        if (document != null) {
            Map<Annotation, Position> result = document.readOnly(new CancelableUnitOfWork<Map<Annotation, Position>, XtextResource>() {

                @Override
                public Map<Annotation, Position> exec(XtextResource state,
                        final CancelIndicator cancelIndicator) throws Exception {
                    MyDslGrammarAccess ga = state.getResourceServiceProvider()
                            .get(MyDslGrammarAccess.class);

                    ICompositeNode root = state.getParseResult().getRootNode();
                    ILeafNode matchNode = NodeModelUtils.findLeafNodeAtOffset(
                            root, selection.getOffset());
                    EObject object = NodeModelUtils
                            .findActualSemanticObjectFor(matchNode);
                    if (object instanceof Greeting) {
                        Greeting g = (Greeting) object;
                        if (matchNode.getGrammarElement() == ga
                                .getGreetingAccess().getIfKeyword_0()) {
                            ICompositeNode objectNode = NodeModelUtils
                                    .findActualNodeFor(object);
                            for (INode n : objectNode.getAsTreeIterable()) {
                                if (n.getGrammarElement() != null
                                        && n.getGrammarElement() == ga
                                                .getGreetingAccess()
                                                .getEndifKeyword_3()) {
                                    Map<Annotation, Position> result = new HashMap<>();
                                    addOccurrenceAnnotation(
                                            DECLARATION_ANNOTATION_TYPE,
                                            document,
                                            new TextRegion(matchNode
                                                    .getOffset(), matchNode
                                                    .getLength()), result);
                                    addOccurrenceAnnotation(
                                            OCCURRENCE_ANNOTATION_TYPE,
                                            document,
                                            new TextRegion(n.getOffset(), n
                                                    .getLength()), result);
                                    return result;

                                }
                            }
                        }
                        if (matchNode.getGrammarElement() == ga
                                .getGreetingAccess().getEndifKeyword_3()) {
                            ICompositeNode objectNode = NodeModelUtils
                                    .findActualNodeFor(object);
                            for (INode n : objectNode.getAsTreeIterable()) {
                                if (n.getGrammarElement() != null
                                        && n.getGrammarElement() == ga
                                                .getGreetingAccess()
                                                .getIfKeyword_0()) {
                                    Map<Annotation, Position> result = new HashMap<>();
                                    addOccurrenceAnnotation(
                                            DECLARATION_ANNOTATION_TYPE,
                                            document,
                                            new TextRegion(matchNode
                                                    .getOffset(), matchNode
                                                    .getLength()), result);
                                    addOccurrenceAnnotation(
                                            OCCURRENCE_ANNOTATION_TYPE,
                                            document,
                                            new TextRegion(n.getOffset(), n
                                                    .getLength()), result);
                                    return result;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    return null;
                }
            });
            if (result != null) {
                return result;
            }
        }
        return super.createAnnotationMap(editor, selection, monitor);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the hints so much. should I bind MyDslOccurrenceComputer  anywhere?

Comment: yes in the ui module    `public Class<? extends IOccurrenceComputer> bindIOccurrenceComputer() { return MyDslOccurrenceComputer.class;}`

Comment: Hi, did you enable mark occurences in the editor? did you try that with your or with my grammar?

Comment: My grammar, it works with selecting only the first characters. but it doesn't select the whole word

Comment: hi which version? the occurrence computer or the CharacterPairMatcher?
can you share your grammar and implementation?

Comment: The occurrence computer it only selects the "d" in end and "n" in begin. My implementation is almost the same as urs I compared it. It only has different grammar rules' names.

Comment: then there must be a problem with your grammar. without you grammar and impl i cannot help to analyze

Comment: have a look at the lengths of the regions you compute - the there is only one char highlighted is the problem of the matcher not the occurence computer

Comment: In the debug it never go through OccurenceComputer. I think there is something in the binding. I can't even find bindIOccuranceComputer to override in MyDslUiModule. I am working with xtext 2.7.2

Comment: first make sure you have mark occurences on (test it in a .xtend file - if not push the corresponding button in the toolbar) there is not one to override. simply add the method to the ui module. have a look at MarkOccurrenceJob and see which class is used.